# The word "attendance" and "at ten dance"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, etymology

When I was at college, my English teachers used to say that the word  attendance was derived from **at**   **ten**  **dance**. In schools the children used to dance at  Ten AM 
in the British Rule and slowly it took the form attendance.

Is there any base for this tale that the word *attendance* really derived from **at**    **ten**   **dance**?

---

This story is prevalent in India.The English teachers who taught me this way were good scholars. I do not know How they believed and spread the story. I suspected the tale but it is very widespread. Some myths have spread into India very mysteriously which have to be debunked on sites like this; this question is intended to dispel widespread misinformation.

Comment: And what did these teachers tell you about *attend,* *attendant,* and *attendee*? The fact that these other words exist should be a clue that the silly etymology your teachers suggested is not correct.  It does sound like a good way to remember the meaning of the word *attendance*.  It reminds me of this book: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6029361-the-weighty-word-book

Comment: Could the teachers have been joking? I mean there's a similar case where the word "assume" is decrypted as "making an ASS out of U and ME", and a lot of people repeat this as a cautionary tale without pointing out the obvious fact that this is nonsense. Same here: the teachers may have assumed that the absurdity of such an explanation is too obvious.

Comment: If there really was a school dance each morning at 10am, I think the more natural way to name it would be "the dance at ten" rather than "the at ten dance".

Comment: @joeytwiddle: It seems highly unlikely, given the British mentality during that era, that schools would actually have children dance, at any time.  Maybe a question for the history site?

Comment: The question in the title is different than the question in the body text. This often  confuses people who read answers that starts with an explicit yes/no, and has already done it here too.

Comment: @jamesqf - "given the British mentality during that era, that schools would actually have children dance" What era? In the 1950s, I was at an ordinary London "infants' school" (ages 5 to 7) and every morning we went into the school hall for "Music and Movement". The big school radio was turned on, for a BBC Schools programme of that name. A lady with a piano would say things like "Children, I want you all to be a tree!", or "Now run around the room like the wind!", or "Make yourself very small like a seed... now grow and grow like a lovely flower!", and play a tune for each activity.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey.So the story might be true.The English teachers who taught me were Christians and are well acquainted with the British,

Comment: @Michael Harvey: The question says "in the British Rule" and "slowly it took the form".  Since India became independent in 1947, what the British were doing in the 1950s is hardly relevant.  Given the "slowly" claim, I think you'd have to look back at least to the practices of the 19th century.  Even when "Music and Movement" became a thing, I would expect different grades to have theirs scheduled throughout the day, rather than a universal 10 AM.

Comment: The 'Music and Movement programmes started in 1935.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is pure nonsense.

"Attendance" is a derivation from the root of the modern English word "attend," which goes back to Old French "atendre," which in turn goes back to Latin "attendere," meaning "to pay attention to."

Like modern German and English, Latin made verbs by combining prepositions and root verbs. So "attendere" was formed by combining the preposition "ad" (meaning "to" or "toward") and the verb "tendere" (meaning "to stretch"). So if you are paying attention, it is natural to stretch toward whoever is speaking.

The verb "tendere" is thought to derive from the root "ten" (meaning to "stretch") in Proto-Indo-European, the partially reconstructed parent language of most languages in Europe, Iran, Afghanistan, Pakistan, and northern India as well as the Americas.

Source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/attend

Comment: As a footnote, the dominant languages in the Americas are Spanish, English, Portuguese, and French, all of which are Indo-European languages.

Comment: As another footnote, none of the American languages is Indo-European, to my best knowledge. (When I hear "languages in the Americas" – without "spoken" – I think of Mayan or Mohawk.)

Comment: Neither Mayan nor Mohawk is a dominant language in the Americas, nor have they been for several centuries. If we were trying to give examples of Indo-European languages that covered the full **historical** range of geographical dispersion, I'd have included Turkey (e.g. Hittite and Luwian) and China (e.g. Tocharian).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is a basis for this tale.  It's a *spelling mnemonic* - a little trick to help us remember how to spell *attendance*.

There are other spelling mnemonics for various tricky English words.  My favourite is *Rhythm helps your two hips move*, for a word that I've always found difficult.

I figure *attendance* could be a tricky word for people learning English - does it have one T or two?  One D or two?  Does it end with -ance, -ence, -ince, -anse, -ense or -inse?  It wouldn't be too unreasonable to spell it *atenddinse* would it?

But if you remember *at ten dance*, you'll never get it wrong.

Unfortunately, from this spelling mnemonic sprang a fictional etymology.  As others pointed out, this is *not* the correct etymology of the word *attendance*.  But sometimes, a good story takes on a life of its own.  Just ask Mr Gorsky!

Comment: Supposedly Neil Armstrong wished good luck to a Mr. Gorsky, although this was a joke: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/good-luck-mr-gorsky/

Answer (score 6):

No. "Attendance" comes from the Latin verb *attendō,* which means "I pay attention". There are actually three Latin roots in "attendance":

- *ad-,* meaning "toward" (cognate with English "at")
- *-tend-,* meaning "stretch"
- *-antia,* which makes an abstract noun out of another word, such as a verb

The idea of "stretching toward" started in reference to aiming a bow and arrow at a target.

The same roots appear in many other English words. If you "attend to" the roots, you can often get an understanding of how English works, including, especially, how English spelling works. Here are some other English words that contain *-tend-.*

- **extend**, whose Latin roots mean "stretch out". As usual, English has Anglo-Saxon and Latin synonyms that carry almost but not quite the same meanings. The synonym from Latin carries more precise meanings, as required in science and administration and other more formal activities. Maybe now it is clear why we speak of **extending** an invitation to someone as well as **extending** a vacation.
- **tension**, which is the opposite of **flexion** in medical terminology for the actions of muscles: tension is "stretching" and flexion is "bending". A **tension headache** results from "stretched" muscles around the head (or at least that's one theory).
- **intend** also [derives from](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=intendo) pointing a finger or aiming a weapon, but this idea is lost in modern English.
- Your belly is **distended** if it's stretched out more than normal.
- …and many others.

Any good dictionary will include an etymology with every word. It's usually worth looking at the etymology to understand the relationships among different words and, sometimes, metaphors that still live in English words. Another excellent resource is [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/attendance#etymonline_v_26687).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not "at-ten-dance".

Before about World War II, new English words were almost always adapted from other languages (partifularly French, Greek and Latin) and from adding prefixes and suffixes to existing words. It's only later that people started making new words from abbreviations (such as acronyms*) or gluing together existing words. So, if anybody proposes to you that a word was made in one of these modern ways, ask yourself if the word is really that modern. "Attendance" is clearly a pretty old word – surely pre-20th-century – so it would have been made by one of the old methods: adding the suffix "-ance" to "attend".

---

* A common false acronym etymology is "posh", which is not derived from "port out, starboard home", supposedly the preferred side of the ship to have one's cabin when sailing between Britain and India. The actual etymology of the word is unclear, but it's probably from the [Romani language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_language).